# Thread-safely closing a boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket being used synchronously

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Given that the `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` and `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` are both marked as non-thread safe as of Boost 1.52.0, is it possible to shutdown a `tcp::acceptor` currently blocking on `accept()` from a separate thread?

I've looked at calling `boost::asio::io_service::stop()` and this looks possible as  `io_service` is thread safe. Would this leave the `io_service` event loop running until any processing being done on the socket are complete?

I am operating synchronously as this is as simple event loop as part of a bigger program and don't want to create additional threads without good reason which I understand async will do.

Comment: Why would you need to call `stop()` from a separate thread? The whole point behind ASIO is that the application is single-threaded. Ideally one of your event triggers (callbacks) is what would invoke `stop()`.

Comment: @chrisaycock "The whole point behind ASIO is that the application is single-threaded." -- this completely is not true.

Comment: `io_service` dispatches handlers, stopping it won't help you. On the other hand, closing acceptor from another thread wouldn't be thread-safe. The only safe way is to use `async_accept` and then close the acceptor from the same thread, if needed.

Comment: @PSIAlt "[Boost.Asio provides the tools to manage these long running operations, without requiring programs to use concurrency models based on threads and explicit locking.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html)"

Comment: *Without requiring*. Since its not required, it can be used from box. Many threads can run `io_service::run()` and handlers will be dispatched to all these threads, so you get async multithread very easily. Also, there is many things that simplify multithreading with asio like **asio::strand** etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having spent some time looking into this there is only 1 thread safe manner in which this can be achieved: by sending a message to the socket (on a thread not waiting on `accept()`) telling the thread to close the socket and the acceptor. By doing this the socket and acceptor can be wholly owned by a single thread.

As pointed out separately, `io_service` is only of use for asynchronous operations.

Comment: Well, this should help in blocking case. Looks like a hack, but if u prefer this ok)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. It's too bad synchronous accept isn't cancelled somehow, just like synchronous  read/read_until is. I used the synchronous calls because that was recommended for simple usage, but now that I've ran into this problem I have to rewrite everything. I get the feeling synchronous calls should be discouraged because of this one call.

Answer (score 4):

If your acceptor is in `async_accept`, you can call `ip::tcp::acceptor::cancel()` to cancel any async operations on it. Note this may fire handlers in this acceptor with the `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` error code.

If you're using synchronous `accept`, it seems impossible since I think it's not related to `io_service` at all.

Comment: Prefer `close`, as `cancel` is not portable enough and might make troubles. See the following article http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/cancel/overload1.html (it talks about `socket`, but applies to `acceptor` as well).

Comment: @PSIAIt I think there is a solution, which I've outlined in an answer. If you take a look and feel I'm incorrect, let me know.

Comment: @IgorR. thanks i was unaware about this windows limitation (i only write on unix)

Answer (score 0):

I think your over thinking this a little. Use a non-blocking accept or a native accept with a timeout within a conditional loop. Add a mutex lock and it's thread safe. You can also use a native select and accept when new connection arrive. Set a timeout and a conditional loop for the select.